# std::make_shared string parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, shared

I have stumbled across a weird weird

animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Animal
  {
  public:
    Animal(std::string aType);
    void someFunction();
  private:
    std::string type;
  };

#endif // ANIMAL_H
```

animal.cpp

```
Animal::Animal(std::string aType) :
  type{aType}
  {
  }
void Animal::someFunction(){
/*Code*/
  }
```

I call std::make_shared on a class "Animal", with as parameter a `std::string`

main.cpp

```
auto sheep = std::make_shared<Animal>("Sheep");
```

Now I also have functions in the animal.cpp class.

If I define `sheep` like this, I can't call any function on it.
(`sheep->` doesn't do anything.)
I get:

```
no matching function for call to 'Animal::someFunction()'
```

However if I change:

```
auto sheep = std::make_shared<Animal>("Sheep Blabla");
```

I can call a function on sheep.

```
sheep->someFunction();
```

gives me all the functions defined in the Animal class.
Just by adding the word "Blabla" behind Sheep.

How is this possible?

Comment: I editted the question, I took away the other parameters

Comment: What does "gives me all the functions defined in the Animal class" mean?

Comment: Now can you please tell us what the problem you have is? You only say that if you make the string longer it works, but you don't tell us what breaks if you use the shorter string. Do you get build errors? What build errors in that case? Do you get runtime errors (crashes)? Where does the debugger tell you the crashes happen?

Comment: Well, it gives me all the functions I can call on it.

Basically sheep-> doesn't result in anything if I don't add a second word to it.
Otherwise I can call 
sheep->breed()
sheep->otherFunction()

etc

I didn't define them here though instead I illustrated with "someFunction"

Comment: I didn't get any compile trouble, it's just that it doesn't recognize the functions

Comment: To make things clearer, the code builds and runs okay, it's just the editor code completion functionality that doesn't work? What editor or IDE do you use? What version?

Comment: QT 5.5.1,  GCC 64bit compiler

Comment: Is this a problem when you run the problem, or a problem with your IDE? Because the example you've given works. https://ideone.com/D1DZFp

Comment: That's the framework and compiler you're using. What about the editor or IDE? Do you mean you're using the [Qt Creator IDE](http://www.qt.io/ide/)?

Comment: Your example does work with Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but it did suggest someFunction() ?

Comment: I'm not sure if questions about bugs in or weird behavior of code completion or intellisense-like editor functionality, is off-topic on SO?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Corresponding close reason includes `unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming`, so the question seems to be **on-topic**. Actually, problem itself is related to programming  more than some other on-topic questions about programming. Of course, there could be cites more suitable for such questions (such as QT Creator forum or bugzilla), but the question is suitable for SO too.